# Ajax request with special characters crashes my app

Tags: json, ajax, special-characters

This Ajax request crashes when the data sent contains special character like "é or â ". I tried many different combinaisons but nothing works. I can also tell you that the data base has been encoded with iso-8859-1; I suspect there is something to do with the JSON.parse but...

Thank you very much for your help.

````
  $(document).ready(function() {
$("#destinataire").change(function(){
$.ajax({

url: "testNicolas.php",
type :'post',
contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
data :{ destinataire : encodeURIComponent($("#destinataire").val())},
success : function(result) {


var toStringResult = JSON.parse(result);

$('#cp').val(toStringResult.cp);
$('#ville').val(toStringResult.ville);
$('#ad1').val(toStringResult.ad1);
$('#ad2').val(toStringResult.ad2);
$('#ATitre').val(toStringResult.aTitre);
$('#nom').val(toStringResult.aNom);
$('#pays').val(toStringResult.pays);
$('#tel').val(toStringResult.tel);
$('#mail').val(toStringResult.mail);```
````

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "crash"? Are there any messages/errors in the  console? What does the server return? BTW, you shouldn't needing `encodeURIComponent`, jQuery does that for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.